# Android TextToSpeech engine not bound, but not on first run

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I am trying to write a super simple app that does TextToSpeech, when a button is clicked.

I ran the app, and on the first time, the TTS worked! (i heard it speak). When I ran it again (and many more time), it didn't speak, even though the code stayed the same. Could anyone tell me how to work it out?

I guess I'm missing something fundamental about how the TTS works, so I'd really appreciate it if you could explain it for a dummy.
Thank you very much, Julius

Here's the layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="test1"
        android:text="Test" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Open local DB" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Open global DB" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {//0

    public void test1(View myView) {
        int e = 1;
        System.out.println("Starting test.....");
        //Step s1=new Step();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "aaaaaaa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Speaker.speak("aaaaaaaaaa", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        Speaker.stop();
        Speaker.shutdown();
    }

    TextToSpeech Speaker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {//1
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Speaker = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {//2
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {//3
                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) System.out.println("success!!!");
                if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {//4
                    Speaker.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                }//4
                else {
                    System.out.println("speak err");
                }
            }//3
        }//2
        );
    }//1

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (Speaker != null) {
            Speaker.stop();
            Speaker.shutdown();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }//1*/
}//0
```

And Finally (thanks for reading until now...) Here's the LogCat:

```
05-11 14:57:35.149 30221 30221 I   art com.mycompany.myapp                      Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
05-11 14:57:35.460 30221 30221 I   TextToSpeech com.mycompany.myapp             Sucessfully bound to com.google.android.tts
05-11 14:57:35.470 30221 30246 D   OpenGLRenderer com.mycompany.myapp           Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
05-11 14:57:35.535 30221 30221 D   Atlas com.mycompany.myapp                    Validating map...
05-11 14:57:35.639 30221 30246 I   Adreno-EGL com.mycompany.myapp               <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 01/14/15, ab0075f, Id3510ff6dc
05-11 14:57:35.641 30221 30246 I   OpenGLRenderer com.mycompany.myapp           Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-11 14:57:35.666 30221 30246 D   OpenGLRenderer com.mycompany.myapp           Enabling debug mode 0
05-11 14:57:35.907 30221 30221 I   TextToSpeech com.mycompany.myapp             Connected to ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService}
05-11 14:57:35.918 30221 30268 I   TextToSpeech com.mycompany.myapp             Set up connection to ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService}
05-11 14:57:35.919 30221 30221 I   System.out com.mycompany.myapp               success!!!
05-11 14:57:36.917 30221 30221 I   System.out com.mycompany.myapp               Starting test.....
05-11 14:57:36.985 30221 30246 V   RenderScript com.mycompany.myapp             Application requested CPU execution
05-11 14:57:37.005 30221 30246 V   RenderScript com.mycompany.myapp             0xb4819e00 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
05-11 14:57:38.465 30221 30221 W   TextToSpeech com.mycompany.myapp             stop failed: not bound to TTS engine
05-11 14:57:38.465 30221 30221 W   TextToSpeech com.mycompany.myapp             shutdown failed: not bound to TTS engine
```

Thanks Again

Answer (score 1):

> **public void shutdown ()**
>   Releases the resources used by the TextToSpeech engine. It is good practice for instance to call this
>   method in the onDestroy() method of an Activity so the TextToSpeech
>   engine can be cleanly stopped.
>
> Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#shutdown()

For this reason the TTS works only the first time, you release the resources of TextToSpeech.

You should remove `Speaker.shutdown();` from `test1` and put in `onDestroy`:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Speaker.shutdown();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```